# JS updating array data, how to make global and access from global

Tags: javascript, arrays, cypress

I have an array where I am updating data to an array in JS but then when I read back the data it says undefined but the data shows perfectly when reading it in the same local as writing it, how can I make everything global i want this data to be read from anywhere in the file?

The array at the top of the file

```
var item = [ // fix bad needs update dirty fix
    { "dirty": " " },
    { "tclass": "", "Order": '', "Fulltitle:": '', "ItemOrderUpdated": false },
    { "tclass": "", "Order": '', "Fulltitle:": '', "ItemOrderUpdated": false },
    { "tclass": "", "Order": '', "Fulltitle:": '', "ItemOrderUpdated": false },
]



function UpdatVal(txt, ordernum, currnety) {
    item[currnety].ItemOrderUpdated = true; // locks this item into being changed
    item[currnety].Fulltitle = txt
    item[currnety].Order = ordernum
    cy.log(`Updating local values ${(item[currnety].Fulltitle)} ${(item[currnety].Orderin)}`) // how to make global
}
```

I call this function when I want to update the data and when I read it its fine and i get the expect result.

```
  cy.log("SUM UP") // at the end of the file
        cy.log(`t1 test local: ${(item[1].tclass)} order:${item[1].Order} Fulltitle:${item[1].Fulltitle} has been updated:${item[1].ItemOrderUpdated}`)
        cy.log(`t2 test local ${(item[2].tclass)} order:${item[2].Order} Fulltitle:${item[2].Fulltitle} has been updated:${item[2].ItemOrderUpdated}`)
        cy.log(`t3 test local ${(item[3].tclass)} order:${item[3].Order} Fulltitle:${item[3].Fulltitle} has been updated:${item[3].ItemOrderUpdated}`)
```

But at the end of the file I check the values again and it comes back as undefined

Comment: Is the "SUM UP" log shown before the "Updating local values" log? If so, that means, that the "SUM UP" get logged before `UpdatVal` has been called. So, the values have not been updated, when logging "SUM UP".

Comment: Probably some asynchrony-related explanation, but you have not provided any code that calls `UpdatVal`, so impossible to say.